# delete button in inline editing + sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list-view

I want the Delete button in the list view to delete the item in inline editing of a share point list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Could you elaborate your question a little?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Ribbon to do the same functionality OOTB, also if you want fast deletion you can use Datasheet view or go to manage content structure.